# The app is asking for consent twice in "app calls api" scenario

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js, msal-angular

I'm using two app registrations and implement the "expose an api" scenario. My **CLIENT_APP** is an angular application using msal-angular library. My **SERVER_APP** is a .NET server that's using "Expose an API" feature and defines a scope. It also lists **CLIENT_APP** as a trusted client application.

**CLIENT_APP** is actually doing most of the heavy lifting in the system and it accesses Azure AD directly using a directory.read.all. The **SERVER_APP** provides settings API and is only interested in knowing the users identity.

My problem is that while doing the initial sign up the users are asked for consent for the **CLIENT_APP** to "View profile" and "Maintain access". That's ok, but immediately after I make a server API call to get settings I'm getting another consent window asking again asking for permissions for **CLIENT_APP** - "View profile" and "Maintain access". However, there's a paragraph in the window:
"If you accept, **SERVER_APP** will also have access to your user profile information."

Is there a way to do this consent thing in one step? It feels like a very confusing user experience (especially when signing in for the first time)

Comment: **AFAIK**, you should not get consent screen twice. When I tried, I got the consent only once like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/P1lYKwS.png). My API permissions are looks like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/c6uPvLo.png).

Comment: yes, my client app lists server api scope as a required permission. looks a lot like yours.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Azure AD **Client App** and added API permissions:

[image]

I created an Azure AD **Server App** and Exposed an API like below:

[image]

> **Note** that: It is inappropriate to get consent screen twice. The user must get the consent screen only once.

For *sample*, I tried to **authorize users** by using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=api://AppID/test.read Directory.Read.All
&state=12345
```

When I tried to sign-in with the user account, I got the **consent once** as below:

[image]

After consenting, user successfully got redirected to the redirect page like below:

[image]

***If still the issue persists***, try the below:

- Configure same API permissions for the Client App and the Server App and try.
- Another approach is you can generate access token for Microsoft Graph and fetch the user profile by using the access token like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID
```

[image]

- It is not possible to call two APIs at a time.
- Try using the one Azure AD App for authorizing users.
- You can also make use of [**On-Behalf Flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#example) to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've fixed the issue by including the SERVER_APP api scope in the initial call to "login.microsoftonline.com". In my case I had to specify the scope while setting up MsalGuard configuration for the page. Since your answer includes this I'm marking it as correct.